# Transient Field in JPA and setting from Query

Tags: java, jpa, transient

How we can load transient fields in JPA from select queries.

For example I have this query:

```
SELECT table1.*, (SELECT SUM(field) from table2 WHERE theField=table1.flag) as total FROM table1;
```

So here I need a transient field called "total" in my bean.

But it seems it is not possible in JPA

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of a `constructor` in `JPQL`

**Query:**

```
SELECT NEW com.foo.entities.Table1(table1.*, (SELECT SUM(field) from table2 WHERE theField=table1.flag) as total) FROM table1;
```

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Table1{

// .. other columns

@Transient
int total;

// table1Field1,table1Field2 etc. map to your table1.* coulmns
public Table1(String table1Field1,int table1Field2,int total){

// ..other assignments here

this.total = total; // transient assignment here

}


}
```

Comment: imagine we have hundred beans with 40 fields for each, the maintenance will kill us :(

Comment: and what happened if we write native sql in this case?

Comment: It seems the solution is switching to MyBatis ;)

Comment: how to achieve this in spring data jpa using specification api?