# Get count of another entity in a foreign relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have two entities.

1. Order (order)
2. OrderStatus (order_status)

In `order_status` table, `order_id` from the first table (`order`) is added as a foreign key.
So if you do something like that, `orderStatusRepository.findAllOrderStatusByOrder(Order order)`, you will get `List<OrderStatus>` having any arbitrary size.
What I want to do, is maintain a count in `order` entity, let's call it `private int orderStatusCount`. Now whenever I do `order.getOrderStatusCount()`,  I should get the count of order statuses for that order. I dont want this field to be persisted in database and I dont want to call the `OrderStatusRepository` again and again. How can I maintain this count? I think that I have to use `@Transient` annotation, but not sure how to populate this field.

Please help.

Comment: I don't think so. Actually you can save the findAllOrderStatusByOrder in a ArrayList and count it. But the problem is meanwhile someone  could change data and you still have the old Count.

Comment: I thought the reason for that field would be that he does not actually want to get all the orderStatuses for performance reasons.
Still, yeah, handling that is cumbersome, calling repository for a count every time seems like the best option. You could maybe slap some cache on the response?

Comment: I will give you guys another perspective. Lets say I have another entity called Freight, and Freight has orders in it. So lets say I want to return the count of orderStatuses for a particular frieght. I know it doesn't make sense, but I do want to convery that the relationship can be nested and calling count recursively has issues.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orderStatuses WHERE orderId IN (...)` is going to be much more efficient (and up-to-date) than any count you slap on individual orders whenever you pull them though. But if you really want to have that field - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696184/transient-field-in-jpa-and-setting-from-query